# Apache web server on Centos

Tags: mysql, linux, apache, centos, webserver

I am trying to host a web server using LAMP. I have installed all the required packages and I can get the server to run. The problem is that when I try to enter the ip address to connect to the server (or enter localhost) I get the error:
Forbidden
You don't have permission to access /index.html on this server.

The weird part is that I can access localhost/info.php and see the php version and info but nothing else in the same folder. All files are placed in /var/www/html and all have the permission -rwxr-x-r-x. My httpd.conf also has all the required settings.

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Some other things I've tried:

I'm pretry sure I set up the server under root because yum install requires root. I also have tried changing the ownership of the var/www/html directory and all the files to apache. As I mentioned above the server is running and I can access the info.php file in the same directory as the html files but I can't access any other file in the directory.

This should be a simple permissions issue but I can't figure out what to change the permissions to. If I change the permissions of all the files to the same thing ex. -rwxr-xr-x why would I be able to access localhost/info.php but not localhost/index.html?

*UPDATE*

So I just moved all the files out of the /var/www/html directory to start clean. I made a new index.html file in that directory. For some reason this file works. Here's the file I made:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

    <html>
        <head>
            <h1>Hello World</h1>
        </head>
    </html>
```

and it displays Hello World on the website. Here are the permissions when I run ls -l:

-rw-r--r-- root root index.html

The weird thing is that when I change the permissions of the original index.html to this and put it back in the /var/www/html directory it still gives the Forbidden error.

also, if I put the info.php file in the var/www/html directory it works and it doesn't seem to matter what the permissions are or what the group or owner is.

I am going to try to copy everything in the original index.html file into the new index.html file I just created.

**EDIT**

Ok so I copied the contents of the original index.html to the new index.html using:

```
cat index.html > html/index.html
```

This worked. Now the index.html file displays. Although, when I try to put in other files like a secondary page, I get the same forbidden error.

I also ran

```
file index.html
```

and it returned:

```
index.html: HTML document text
```

Although it doesn't appear like it, could there possibly be an issue when saving the html file from notepad++? Would this cause a 403 Forbidden error?

I've been working on this for what seems like forever and haven't been able to find a solution.

Comment: I also tried turning off iptables:    service iptables stop, without this I cannot access the server

Comment: Not sure there is enough information here. You may have set it up with the wrong user. Web servers have special permissions / users they run as because of the inherent risks.  Also, check if SE linux is enabled on your Centos, and disable it at least until you have this figured out. No simple answers, as it will take some diagnosing.

Comment: I also tried disabling selinux but so far that is not the issue